# MS Access - "file already in use" error on split database

Tags: ms-access

I have a split database in MS Access 2010 on Windows 7.

The back end is on a networked drive in a folder that only some people have write permissions; everyone has read permissions.

Every user has their own copy of the front end stored on their local machine.

Both BE & FE are set to open as shared, not exclusive, for all users.

If a user with read-only permissions tries to get on while another user with read-only permissions is on, they can get on fine.

If a user with read-only permissions tries to get on while a user with write permissions has it open, they get a message saying " file already in use" and they can't open the database.

If a user with write permissions tries to open the database while a user with read-only permissions has it open, it opens as read-only for this user as well.

Do ALL users of a split database need full access?  I really don't want everyone to be able to make edits.  Anything I can do to get this to work?

Comment: When you talk about "permissions", are you talking about Windows File/Folder permissions? If yes, I believe everyone will have to have Read and Write permissions to the folder (and it's files) that stores your database. You need to implement security/permissions a different way or move your data to SQL Server which allows for more control over security/permissions.

Comment: yes, I do mean Windows permissions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue has certainly something to do with the fact that the read-only clients can't manage the `.laccdb` lock file since they don't have write permission to the shared folder in which the database file resides.

When the database is opened in shared mode, each client will create or update the lock file.
It's likely that since read-only clients can't create the lock file, they fall-back to believing they are in exclusive mode.
Once a full-access client creates the lock file, any subsequent client will attempt to use it, and read-only clients will fail since they can't update the lock.

Some documentation regarding lock files:[Introduction to .ldb files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299373/EN-US)

If you want to solve your issue, you must grant full access to the folder for all clients, but you can restrict access to the `.accdb` database file itself to the group of clients that are not supposed to be able to modify data in it.

Alternatively, if you are not using Access 2007/2010 features, you can revert to using an older `.mdb` file as a backend and use their old-style group security features.

Ultimately, if you really want to control access, you may need to roll-you-own security scheme from within the client, forcing users to log-in (or use their the identity of their machine) and update your forms' data edit properties depending on what that particular user/machine is allowed to do.

Comment: +1 Absolutely, its the read/only folder setting which prevents user's from creating and/or modifying the lock file.