# Delphi 7 app using MSAccess database blocks access by MSaccess

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7, ado

I have an old Delphi 7 application that I fixed up a bit. It uses an Access database. There are about 150 users who all open the application remotely and access the database in parallel. Before I started fixing things (heh), this worked nicely (apart from bugs in the Delphi application), even if the database was occasionally a bit slow.

Now that I added a few features and two new tables I suddenly have really weird problems.

1. MSAccess can access the Database (2010 version). This means: Double-clicking the file will open MSAccess and open the database file.
2. The Delphi 7 app can access the database.
3. Two or more instances of the Delphi app can share the database provided I change the original ConnectionString Mode from "ReadWrite" to "Share Deny None" (entire connection string below).
4. Once an instance of the Delphi app is running, the database file **cannot** be opened any more by double-clicking it. (Nothing happens when I do this). However, I can open MSAccess and open the Database file from within it. That will work.

Connection String:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
User ID=Admin;Data Source=DBPath;
Mode=Share Deny None;
Extended Properties="";
Persist Security Info=False;
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****;
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don`t Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False
```

I still need to look at all the suggestions made by Renaud Bompuis about the security settings for the shares, but I'll have to unearth an Admin for this so it may take a while.

Comment: Sorry 4 OT, but Access might not be the appropriate database for 150 users

Comment: Have you changed permissions on the folder by any chance? The folder where the Access db resides needs read/write permissions.

Comment: @bummi I have no choice there. The app is in use. Besides, it works! I always think that MSAccess is pretty underrated.

Comment: @Remou I'll check, but I can't see why in this case the Delphi app is allowed access and MSAccess isn't.

Comment: MSAccess by default opens databases with exclusive access. You can overrule this on a per database basis. IIRC there was/is an option for this in the database options under the tools menu. No idea where they have moved that option in recent MS Access versions.

Comment: take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/13e1b2fe-969a-4405-930b-4322e26bddfc/)

Comment: @kobik: this is it!!! Thanks!! Now I'll have to find out how to accept an answer... (sorry newbie heire)

Comment: @user1455903, I just gave you a lead. I don't know which solution there helped you... You might want to post an answer yourself, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of the database on your machine, make sure that you can open it using Access without getting any error. Fix that first if you're getting issues. Maybe compact and repair the database.

Make sure that the remote folder you open the database from has been added to the list of *Trusted Locations* in Access (same for the local folder where you open your database from).

If you can open the database locally, but not when it's on a remote share, then make sure that the security settings for the shares allows you read **and** write access to the whole share so the database engine can properly create the `.laccdb` or `.ldb` lock file.
See question [MS Access - “file already in use” error on split database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958873/ms-access-file-already-in-use-error-on-split-database) for similar issues.

Basically, there is no reason for Access not to be able to open the remote database, even while other users are connected to it.

When you ask questions here, remember to post as much details as possible.
For instance here, you should post the exact connection string details you are using; you should also mention the exact error messages you are getting when trying to open the database from Access as it can help us identify the issue.

Comment: One suggestion of yours helped: Compact and repair. As for the rest of your suggestions, I edited my original post.